# Why does <amp-iframe> show overflow child element？

Tags: javascript, iframe, amp-html

```
<amp-iframe id="sample-resizable-iframe"
                    title="Resizable iframe example from 200x200 to 300x300 "
                    width="350"
                    height="450"
                    sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"
                    resizable
                    frameborder="0"
                    src="xxx/amp-chat.php?orgId=10110&title=Home">
            <amp-img layout="fill" src="xxx/amp-site/placeholder.png" placeholder></amp-img>
            <div overflow tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Read more!">Read more!</div>
        </amp-iframe>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa5bC.png)

Anybody know why?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but while using amp-iframe came across few observations which may answer this.

Iframe resizing is used when you have an iframe of non-fixed size. So you render iframe and use postMessage from iframe to resize it to desired size. Here AMP ask you to add overflow button.

Many times i observed if you scroll to AMP Iframe location on page on load even before it resizes to desired size on own and when it's not completely loaded. In that case i observed It's fails to re-size on it's own and this 'overflow' button appears over it. It observed mostly with mobiles. Then by clicking on this button you can re-size it manually. Other wise this button is hidden and doesn't appears on iFrame.